# alternativa a toggleClass

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estoy tratando de usar el toggle class para alternar la clase active pero a veces funciona y a otras veces no, entonces que otra alternativa podría usar?

```
<div class="talla-color-guia">Talla</div>
<div id="see-more-info-product">Alternar</div>
```

```
$("#see-more-info-product").click(function(){
  $(".talla-color-guia").toggleClass("active");
});
```

intente algo asi pero no me la remueve, solo la agrega

```
$("#see-more-info-product").click(function(){
   $(".talla-color-guia").addClass("active");
        
   if ($(".talla-color-guia.active").length){
      $(this).removeClass("active");
   }       
});
```

Comment: podes usar el hasClass de JQuery para validar si existe la clase active, aunque no entiendo porque te fallaria el toggleClass

Comment: pues tampoco entiendo porque no me funciona, entonces ps por eso busco una alternativa

Comment: Te aseguro que `toogleClass()` funciona. Si en tu caso no lo está haciendo es porque tienes algo en tu código que está afectando. Yo miraría la causa de esto en vez de buscar alternativas, porque seguramente las alternativas que busques también te funcionen solamente a veces. En el código que muestras en tu pregunta no se puede ver la causa, ya que en el ejemplo `toogleClass()` funcionaría el 100% de las veces.

Comment: si amigo tienes toda la razon, le puse logs y cuando doy clic se ejecuta 8 veces, razon que no se porque, pero ps seguire revisando.

Comment: se podra de alguna manera limitar o evitar que se repita?, no tengo control a todo el codigo, entonces lo que hago es agregar nuevo.

Comment: ¿Yienes control de esa parte de código? Quizá poniendo alguna clase y/o id (en lugar de `.talla-color-guia` y `#see-more-info-product`) con un nombre más específico (y que quizá sea única en todo el documento) te asegures que no haya interferencias con otros elementos de la página.

Comment: Bueno el problema era que al dar clic, se ejecutaba un evento varias veces, entonces le puse el **.off** y se soluciono